# Find the minimum value of $f(x) = x + \frac{x}{x^2 + 1} + \frac{x(x + 4)}{x^2 + 2} + \frac{2(x + 2)}{x(x^2 + 2)}$

Tags: inequality

Find the minimum value of
$$f(x) = x + \frac{x}{x^2 + 1} + \frac{x(x + 4)}{x^2 + 2} + \frac{2(x + 2)}{x(x^2 + 2)}$$ for $x > 0.$

I'm not sure how to start this problem. I think AM-GM is the best way, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I  solved your problem. Show please your attempts and I'll show my solution.

Comment: I explained that I'm not sure how to start, so I would like a hint please.

Comment: While the mathematics should rule the day, it wouldn't hurt to plot the function.

Comment: Is the answer $5$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$f'(x) = \frac{(x^4+x^2+2)(x^3+2x^2+2x+2)(x^3-2x^2+2x-2)}{x^2(x^2+1)^2(x^2+2)^2}.$$
Because $x>0,$ so
$$f'(x) = 0 \Rightarrow  x = x_0 = \frac{\sqrt[3]{17+3\sqrt{33}}}{3}-\frac{2}{3\sqrt[3]{17+3\sqrt{33}}}+\frac{2}{3} \approx 1.5437$$
Therefore
$$f(x) \geqslant f(x_0) = 5.$$
So $f(x)_{\min} = 5,$ equality occur when $x=x_0.$

[image]

**Note.** The SOS form
$$f(x) = 5 + \frac{(x^3-2x^2+2x-2)^2}{x(x^2+1)(x^2+2)}  \geqslant 5.$$
**P/s.** How do center an image?

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=x + \frac{x}{x^2 + 1} + \frac{x(x + 4)}{x^2 + 2} + \frac{2(x + 2)}{x(x^2 + 2)}$$
$$f(x)=\frac{x^6+x^5+8 x^4+3 x^3+12 x^2+2 x+4}{x \left(x^2+1\right) \left(x^2+2\right)}$$
$$f'(x)=\frac{ x^{10}+x^8-2 x^6-8 x^4-12 x^2-8}{\big[x \left(x^2+1\right) \left(x^2+2\right)\big]^2}$$
$$x^{10}+x^8-2 x^6-8 x^4-12 x^2-8=\left(x^3-2 x^2+2 x-2\right) \left(x^3+2 x^2+2 x+2\right) \left(x^4+x^2+2\right)$$

- The last factor does not show any real root.
- The first cubic  shows only one real root $x_1$
- The second cubic  shows only one real root $x_2$ which in fact $x_2=-x_1$

So, let us solve $x_1$ using the hyperbolic method
$$x_1=\frac{2}{3} \left(1+\sqrt{2} \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{17}{2
   \sqrt{2}}\right)\right)\right)$$
Rrplacing, we have the simple $f(x_1)=5$ and $f(x_2)=-3$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution by A.M-G.M
$$f(x)=x+\frac{x}{x^2+1}+\frac{x(x+4)}{x^2+2}+\frac{2(x+2)}{x(x^2+2)}$$
$$f(x)=x+\frac{x}{x^2+1}+\frac{x^2+4x}{x^2+2}+\frac{2}{x^2+2}+\frac{4}{x(x^2+2)}$$
$$f(x)=\frac{x(x^2+2)}{x^2+1}+\frac{x^2}{x^2+2}+\frac{4x}{x^2+2}+\frac{2}{x^2+2}+\frac{4}{x(x^2+2)}$$
$$f(x)=\frac{x(x^2+2)}{x^2+1}+1+\frac{4x}{x^2+2}+\frac{4}{x(x^2+2)}$$
$$f(x)=1+\frac{x(x^2+2)}{x^2+1}+\frac{4(x^2+1)}{x(x^2+2)}\geq 1+2\sqrt{\frac{x(x^2+2)}{x^2+1}.\frac{4(x^2+1)}{x(x^2+2)}}$$
$$f(x)\geq 5$$
By the AM-GM definition, equality occurs when$$\frac{x(x^2+2)}{x^2+1}=\frac{4(x^2+1)}{x(x^2+2)}$$
or$$x^3-2x^2+2x-2=0$$ which has a real root lying between $1$ and $2$

Answer (score 0):

This is my first-ever answer on Stack Exchange and Mathematics Exchange, so please forgive me if I make any mistakes here.

Here's my solution using the AM - GM inequality:

$$f(x) = x + \frac {x} {x^2 + 1} + \frac {x(x + 4)} {x^2 + 2} + \frac {2(x + 2)} {x(x^2 + 2)}$$

$$= \frac {x(x^2 + 1) + x} {x^2 + 1} + \frac {x^2(x + 4) + 2(x + 2)} {x(x^2 + 2)}$$

$$= \frac {x^3 + 2x} {x^2 + 1} + \frac {x^3 + 4x^2 + 2x + 4} {x(x^2 + 1)}$$

$$= \frac {x(x^2 + 2)} {x^2 + 1} + \frac {4x^2 + 4} {x(x^2 + 2)} + \frac {x^3 + 2x} {x(x^2 + 2)}$$

$$= \frac {x(x^2 + 2)} {x^2 + 1} + \frac {4(x^2 + 1)} {x(x^2 + 2)} + 1.$$

Using the AM - GM inequality:

$$\frac {x(x^2 + 2)} {x^2 + 1} + \frac {4(x^2 + 1)} {x(x^2 + 2)} \ge 2\sqrt{4}.$$

$$4 + 1 = 5.$$

So $f(x) \ge 5.$

Now we have to check if $f(x) = 5$ is valid or not.

In order for $f(x) = 5, \frac {x(x^2 + 2)} {x^2 + 1} = 2$

So:

$$x(x^2 + 2) = 2x^2 + 2$$

$$x^3 - 2x^2 + 2x - 2 = 0.$$

Now, let $g(x) = x^3 - 2x^2 + 2x - 2 = 0.$

When we plug in $x = 1$ and $x = 2$, $g(x) = -1$ and $2$ respectively.

Thus, meaning that there is a positive root in $g(x).$

So the minimum value of $f(x)$ is $\boxed{5.}$

Furthermore, on the AM - GM step, we could have done this instead:

$$\frac {x(x^2 + 2)} {x^2 + 1} + \frac {4(x^2 + 1)} {x(x^2 + 2)} + 1\ge 3\sqrt [3] {4}.$$

$$f(x) \ge 3\sqrt [3] {4}.$$

We plug back in $f(x) = 3\sqrt [3] {4}$ to find that x is a complex number:
[WolfRam Alpha's Complex Solutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOerz.png)

- William R Li

Comment: Your answer is almost identical to the one given by **Maverick** three years ago.

Comment: No, mine is different.